# AngularJs build a angular-chartjs App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

Does anybody know why i always get a error message like

> angular.js:11607Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'TestCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

I really don't know why this is happening. Here are some files:

App.js

```
(function(module, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  var $ = require('jquery'),
      _ = require('underscore'),
      angular = require('angular'),
      modulePrototype = require('modulePrototype'),
      chartjs = require('angular-chartjs'),
      ChartController = require('./Controller/ChartController'),
      AjaxService = require('../../Utilities/Service/AjaxService/Service'),
      ajaxServiceInstance;

  var chart = modulePrototype.extend({

    /**
     * @param el
     */
    initialize : function(el) {
      this.el = el;
      this.$el = $(el);

      this.chartApp = angular.module('chart', ['chartjs']);
      this.AppCtrl = new ChartController(this.chartApp, this.el);

      var _this = this;
    }

  });

  module.exports = chart;

})(module);
```

Controller.js

```
/**
 * AngularJS Chart App
 *
 * @module ChartController
 */

var $ = require('jquery'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    angular = require('angular'),
    ChartController;

/**
 * UserController
 * @param angularApp
 * @constructor
 */
ChartController = function(angularApp) {
    'use strict';

    angularApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        console.log('hey');
    });

    return angularApp;
};

// Return the Constructor.
module.exports = ChartController;
```

And the .html file:

```
<div ng-app="chart">

    <section class="test-chart" ng-controller="TestCtrl" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;">
        <article class="chart-container" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; height: 70%;">
            <cjs-line dataset="activeData" responsive="true"></cjs-line>
        </article>
        <button ng-click="swapData()">Swap Data</button>
    </section>

</div>
```

I just want to create a simple chart view for some datas.
Thanks in advance, regards.

Comment: This seems like a needlessly convoluted way of initialising your Angular app. Why don't you just declare it with a simple `angular.module('chart',['chartjs']).controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http){/* code here */})`

Comment: Aron, if i remove the this.chartApp and this.AppCtrl line and insert you solution, it's still the same error message. regards

Comment: You don't need any of those 2 files at all. Just have one app.js file with that line in it. That will work. If you then want to include jquery and underscore, depending on how you want to use them you will either need to include them as module dependencies (eg for underscore) or just make them available as globals by including them in script tags (eg jquery).